# Jenkins Slave goes offline during the build

Tags: windows-server-2012, jenkins, slave

A Jenkins 1.651 master and slave have been installed on a Windows Server 2012.
The slave is dedicated to run Selenium tests, but most of the time it goes offline:

```
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
ERROR: slave-tester is offline; cannot locate jdk7
```

and

```
Apr 20, 2016 2:20:05 PM INFO jenkins.slaves.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver handle
Disconnecting slave-tester as we are reconnected from the current peer
Apr 20, 2016 2:20:17 PM WARNING org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub run
Communication problem
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$Pointer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:306)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:561)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 20, 2016 2:20:17 PM WARNING jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol$Handler$1 onClosed
NioChannelHub keys=2 gen=88003: Computer.threadPoolForRemoting [#2] for slave-tester terminated
java.io.IOException: Connection aborted: org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$MonoNioTransport@17d0b4b[name=xxx]
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$NioTransport.abort(NioChannelHub.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:628)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer$Pointer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.FifoBuffer.receive(FifoBuffer.java:306)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub.run(NioChannelHub.java:561)
    ... 6 more
```

slave logs:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 2.53.3
Slave.jar version: 2.53.3
This is a Windows slave
This is a Windows slave
Connection terminated
Connection terminated
ERROR: Failed to install restarter
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:297)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.handle(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:61)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$2.run(NioChannelHub.java:594)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to slave-tester(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.install(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:52)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.access$000(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:33)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:39)
    at jenkins.slaves.restarter.JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller$1.call(JnlpSlaveRestarterInstaller.java:36)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1080)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport$1.handle(AbstractByteArrayCommandTransport.java:61)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.nio.NioChannelHub$2.run(NioChannelHub.java:594)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: Command close created at
    at hudson.remoting.Command.<init>(Command.java:56)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1074)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.<init>(Channel.java:1072)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1156)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.close(Channel.java:1138)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$CloseCommand.execute(Channel.java:1079)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$1.handle(Channel.java:501)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:60)
```

What is causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: can you provide the Jenkins logs? this is normally in `%JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.out` and `%JENKINS_HOME%/jenkins.err` also is there any errors within the Windows Error log?

Comment: `most of the time it goes offline`? Please indicate the frequency.

Comment: @Alfred half of the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Similar issues**

- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27251
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6817
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28155
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28826
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22932
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTQAINFRA-928
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743908/jenkins-slave-connection-aborted
- https://mailman.owncloud.org/pipermail/jenkins/2015-July/006091.html
- https://mailman.boum.org/pipermail/tails-dev/2014-December/007732.htm

**Possible solution**

Based on [this source](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204204494-Windows-slave-cannot-be-launched-via-Java-Web-Start), part of the stack trace:

```
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and experiencing the same issue in the office upgrading the jdk7 to the latest oracle-jdk8 could solve the issue.

**If the issue persists:**

1. Please indicate exactly when the issue occurs so it could be possible to reproduce the issue
2. Please add the Jenkins build log of the build that is causing the issue. Perhaps there is a specific task that is executed by the job that is causing the issue.
3. View the windows task manager while building the job
4. Please add the log of one of the successful builds and the log of one of the failed builds

Comment: we're trying your solution (jdk8 for the specified job), if it works I'll be glad to give you the bounty :)

Comment: same error, different java version :( ERROR: slave-tester is offline; cannot locate jdk8u77 
1) the error occurrs randomly
2) the same task (we have only 1 with this issue) works half of the times

Comment: I'm testing this solution too even if it seems a bit extreme https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22932

Comment: @Sim1 How many jobs run on the slave? Could you add the full log of the job that is failing sometimes?

Comment: Could you add the log of one of the successful builds, and the log of one of the failed builds?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the file which solved my problem
rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol.secret

INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to /home/ubuntu/remoting
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Remoting version: 4.13
This is a Unix agent
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jenkins.slaves.StandardOutputSwapper$ChannelSwapper to constructor java.io.FileDescriptor(int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of jenkins.slaves.StandardOutputSwapper$ChannelSwapper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Evacuated stdout
ERROR: Failed to load the key: jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol.secret
java.lang.Error: Failed to load the key: jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol.secret